# Apache reverse proxy infinite loop

Tags: apache, redirect

I am stuck on an apache configure issue. The website keeps loading. It seems like an infinite redirection issue.

I am setting up a reverse proxy. The purpose is to host two web servers(Wordpress and Flask) on the same machine. I want some requests go to wordpress and some of goes to Flask. My solution is to let Wordpress listening on port 8080 and Flask listening on port 8081. In the setting below, I am trying to redirect all requests to port 8080(I will add flask later). But, it doesn't work. The website keeps loading. Can I get some help?

My setting is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /wordpress/wp-content
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName aa.mcmaster.ca
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://aas.mcmaster.ca/:8080
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://aaas.mcmaster.ca/:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below ProxyPass and test.

```
ProxyPass / http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8080/
```